# Mysql cpu usage is too high

Tags: mysql, left-join, innodb

My server config is this:

1- (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz) x2

2- (Ram DDR4 8G) x16 128G total ram

And this is mysql configuration:

```
[mysqld]

# log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.err
# pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

innodb_undo_log_truncate        = off

# general
table_open_cache                = 200000
table_open_cache_instances      = 64
back_log                        = 3500
max_connections                 = 100000

# files
innodb_file_per_table           = ON            # New
innodb_log_file_size            = 16G            # c
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_open_files               = 4000

# buffers
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 64G            # c
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 24
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
key_buffer_size                 = 64M

# tune
innodb_doublewrite              = 1
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      = 90
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  = 10
# 1innodb_lru_scan_depth                = 2048
innodb_page_cleaners            = 4
join_buffer_size                = 512KB
sort_buffer_size                = 512KB
innodb_use_native_aio           = 1

#innodb_spin_wait_delay         = 96
innodb_adaptive_flushing        = 1
innodb_flush_neighbors          = 0
innodb_read_io_threads          = 16
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16
innodb_io_capacity              = 1500
innodb_io_capacity_max          = 2500
innodb_purge_threads            = 4
innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = 0
max_prepared_stmt_count         = 1000000
innodb_monitor_enable           = '%'
performance_schema              = ON
max_allowed_packet              = 268435456
thread_handling                 = pool-of-threads
```

My website use huge data in join and sort and always at least 200 visitors online.

Response is too low speed and cpu usage more than 200%

```
mysql   0     CPU:220.53%     Memory:22.08% /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

I think my Mysql configuration is wrong.
What should i do?

Comment: I'd start with increasing the join_buffer_size and the sort_buffer_size.  Change one parameter at a time and measure for improvements.  See [A Modern Guide to MySQL Performance Monitoring](https://www.metricfire.com/blog/a-modern-guide-to-mysql-performance-monitoring/) for more information.

Comment: Are your queries optimized? maybe JOINs are using too much CPU. (Nested loops)

Comment: @alirakiyan I used index key in join

Comment: Guess Queries are not optimized. Please try to read slow query log on mysql - that would be good starting poing

Comment: @Vlada I optimized one query, Now it's better, but CPU usage is 140%

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;   - NOT show status; for summary
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Farshid Please consider posting additional information requested May 6 at 14:21 for suggestions to reduce CPU utilization and reduce WAITing time for query completion.

Comment: @Farshid We are doing one analysis, can you share based on what context you have configured these 3 variables(table_open_cache,  table_open_cache_instances, max_connections) it's almost in max value in your system.